# Launchdarkly Click conversion metric not registering in react next is project

Tags: react-native, next.js, react-hooks, launchdarkly

Just as the title suggests.

Launchdarkly is initialized in _app.tsx, but click events are not being tracked by launchdarkly.

Flags can be set, string can be changed, however, these have to be initialized with the useFlags().